# Aerospike randomly returning nil errors when using Query() with Go client

Tags: go, aerospike

I'm experiencing some strange behavior.  I'm trying to set up a small webapp that fetches some data using Aerospike 3.5 Community running on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.  I'm using the default aerospike.conf file (using the 'test' namespace) and am following the example of how to query [here](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/docs/client.md#query).

When I attempt to query some records with a filter, the Errors channel *randomly* is returning a nil error.  (This example points to my dev database instance).

To replicate, compile and run the following multiple times, you'll see either data returned or a panic:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
)

func main() {

    c, err := aerospike.NewClient("52.7.157.46", 3000)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    recs := liststuff(c)

    fmt.Printf("got results: %v", recs)
}

func liststuff(client *aerospike.Client) []*aerospike.Record {

    // fetch some records with a filter
    stm := aerospike.NewStatement("test", "products")
    stm.Addfilter(aerospike.NewEqualFilter("visible", 1))
    fmt.Println("querying...")
    recordset, err := client.Query(nil, stm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // collect results into a slice
    recs := []*aerospike.Record{}
L:
    for {
        select {
        case rec, chanOpen := <-recordset.Records:
            if !chanOpen {
                break L
            }
            fmt.Println("found record %v", rec)
            recs = append(recs, rec)
        case err := <-recordset.Errors:
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            } else {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("error nil when it should exist"))
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    return recs
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to post an update, both Errors and Records channels are closed automatically when the record stream is over from the server-side, hence the nil value from the Errors channel.

So this wasn't an error after all. We've updated the thread in our Aerospike user forum post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the aerospike package but running your example code show that it always panics no matter if it returns data or not.

That means that the `Errors` channel always sends either an `error` or `nil`. If that's the expected behavior you'd have to handle it accordingly and only panic when the error is not `nil`.

Sending `nil` on the channel still means that a value is being sent on the channel and it will trigger the select statement. Thus the panic on a `nil error`.

The randomness you see, i.e. sometimes data is returned and sometimes it isn't is due to the nature of the select statement. If both data and a `nil error` are being sent at the same time both cases are true and select will [pseudo randomly select](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) one of the two.

> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that
>   can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.
>   Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there
>   is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one
>   of the communications can proceed.

If it selects the data channel first it will print the data and then on the next iteration select the error channel and panic. If it picks the error channel first it panics and the data never prints.

Comment: But note that 1. It _doesn't_ panic every time, you can try it, it returns data 50% of the time  2.  It should never send an error on the error channel unless something is really wrong, I shouldn't have to worry about race conditions.  Good points though. Thanks.

Comment: I did run your code snippet a dozen times or so and it paniced every time. As you say it does return data about half the time but then still panics. Perhaps you didn't mean to panic on the nil errors but the code snippet does. And you are correct that the Errors channel should only send non-nil errors so that you don't have to worry about it, but clearly it doesn't  So that seems to be an error in the package.  If you change the panic on nil error to just print and remove the return stmt you'll see that it returns data every time.

Comment: After testing more, it's always returning _something_ on that error channel and 100% of the time err is nil, which to me is strange.  I asked in the Aerospike forums for a clear answer:  https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-randomly-returning-nil-errors-when-using-query-with-go-client/1346/1    so we'll see what they say

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a legit bug and should be fixed soon:  https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-randomly-returning-nil-errors-when-using-query-with-go-client/1346